# XML::Twig - Inplace editing

Tags: perl, perl-module, xml-twig, xdp-pdf

I'm trying to append timestamp at the end of xdp file. I am using [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig). On running the script timestamp (`<testing>4619314911532861</testing>`) gets added at the end but the output is coming on STDOUT instead of `testdata.xdp`. What am I missing?

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig=XML::Twig->new(pretty_print => 'indented');
my $file = 'testdata.xdp';
$twig->parsefile_inplace($file, '.bak');
my $root= $twig->root;
my @children= $root->children;

foreach my $child (@children){
    my $eblg= new XML::Twig::Elt( 'testing', localtime);
    $eblg->paste( 'last_child', $child);
}

$twig->flush;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is - `parsefile_inplace` works as a standalone thing. It replaces the source file immediately after the `parse` operation is complete.

So to use it like that, you need to do your 'work' within `twig_handlers`. If you do this, it'll parse/modify/overwrite.

E.g.:

```
sub insert_after_all {
    my ( $twig, $element ) = @_;
    my $eblg= new XML::Twig::Elt( 'testing', localtime);
    $eblg->paste( 'last_child', $element);
    $twig -> flush;
}

my $twig =  XML::Twig->new(pretty_print => 'indented', 
                      twig_handlers => { '_all_' => \&insert_after_all } );
 my $file = 'testdata.xdp';
 $twig->parsefile_inplace($file, '.bak');
```

Otherwise - rename the source, and `print {$new_fh} $twig -> sprint;`

Comment: Replaced `$twig->flush;` with `$twig->print`. That also threw output to STDOUT.

Comment: OK. Can you check your XML::Twig version?

Comment: It's `3.49` which is the latest version.

Comment: Ah, no I see the problem! it's how `parsefile_inplace` works. Editing answer.

Comment: The documentation isn't particularly clear on that one, I know. A quick rummage through the source helped me figure out what was happening.

Comment: Strange that your code is giving empty testdata.xdp file.

Comment: I don't have your source data. Could you try putting a `flush` in the handler?